# Gnuplot : Coloring background according to data range

Tags: colors, gnuplot, background-color

I plot a data file containing 2 columns as a line. I also have data ranges for the x axis that I would like to use to color the background.

For example, in the data range from 41 to 70, I would like to color the background blue.

I know that these commands can color background but I haven't yet figured out how to use x values :

```
set obj 1 rectangle behind from graph 0, graph 0 to graph 1, graph 1
set obj 1 fillstyle solid 1.0 fillcolor rgb "blue"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gnuplot supports multiple coordinate systems.  As your already aware, there's `graph` where 0,0 is the lower left corner of the graph and 1,1 is the upper right corner of the graph.  There's also `screen`.  (0,0 is the lower left corner of the "screen").  The axes you're looking for is `first`.  Note that you can even mix coordinate systems.  the point `first 50, graph 0` is at the bottom of the graph at the point 50 on the x axis.  Putting this all together, you should be able to set your rectangle as:

```
set obj 1 rectangle behind from first 41, graph 0 to first 70, graph 1 back
set obj 1 fillstyle solid 1.0 fillcolor rgb "blue"
```

*I also added "back" to the command so that the rectangle is drawn behind all the other plot elements*